# Reverse calculation of sqrt()

Tags: php, sqrt

I'm making a online RPG game where I use this math formula (found online) to calc exp -> level.

```
$level = (25 + sqrt(625 + 100 * $exp)) / 50;
```

I have tried for days to make a script to reverse it.
My goal is to make a function to calc the amount of exp required for a level.

Comment: well sqrt is the opposite of pow...

Comment: @rak007: which would be a poor implementation. This factorises quite nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By rearrangement and a bit of factorisation,

`$exp = 25 * $level * ($level - 1)`

Comment: The edit was incorrect ;-) Note the deliberate -25 and +25.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed... My bad! :)

Comment: We'll publish jointly.

Comment: So, being bored enough for sticking with it, it turns out that your factorization is actually incorrect. Rearranging the equation gets us to `(50l-25)^2 - 625 = 100e`, with everyone agreeing thus far. `(50l-25)^2 - 625 != (50l - 25)*(50*l + 25)` though. :/ Turns out that it's possible to simplify it all the way down to polynomial with non-fractional coefficients, though...

Comment: @EmilH: You're right. We will certainly publish jointly. Oops.

Comment: Damn squares always trips me up as well! You still get to be first name, though. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's possible to simplify even further to:

```
$exp = 25*($level*$level - $level);
```

Derivation:

```
l=(25 + sqrt(625 + 100e))/50
50l=25 + sqrt(625 + 100e)
50l-25=sqrt(625 + 100e)
(50l-25)^2=625 + 100e
(25*(2l-1))^2=625 + 100e
625*((2l-1))^2=625 + 100e
625*((2l-1))^2 - 625= 100e
625*((2l-1)^2 - 1) = 100e
625*((2l-1)^2 - 1)/100 = e
125*((2l-1)^2 - 1)/20 = e
25*((2l-1)^2 - 1)/4 = e
25*(4l^2-4l + 1- 1)/4 = e
25*(4l^2-4l)/4 = e
25*(l^2-l) = e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$exp = ((((50 * $level) - 25)**2) - 625)/100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$exp = (pow(50 * $level - 25, 2) - 625) / 100;
```